# Forward with request parameter in model/

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

Is there a way to do a forward in

```
lib/model/doctrine/table.class.php?
```

I do have a query. When the query returns a false forward with the $input. Or is there a another way to do it.

Thanks!

Gunnar

Comment: What do you mean by forward ? if its redirecting web browser we don't do this inside model, better doing it inside the action layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not do this in your model ... do it in your action :

action.class.php :

```
$result = Doctrine_Core::getTable('yourtable')->find(1234); // or any query
if (!$result) // check if the result is false / empty
{
   $this->forward('default','notfound'); // specify your forwarding module/action
   or 
   $this->forward404(); // default 404 error
}
```

[Symfony 1.4 docs on this subject](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_sub_skipping_to_another_action)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use in your action :

```
$result = Doctrine_Core::getTable('yourtable')->find(1234); // or any query
$this->redirectIf(!$result, '@homepage');
```

Or

```
$this->redirect404If(!$result, 'Your message');
```